# How to replace XML with sub-elements

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have the following:

`<stats>Some line<br>Some Other line</stats>`

and I want it to become this:

`<ul class="bar"><li>Some line</li><li>Other Line</li></ul>`

I tried doing it with `BeautifulSoup` but seem to be having some issues with it.  Can someone lend me a hand here?

Thanks

Comment: BeautifulSoup should get you rolling, it has the needed selectors to get the text inside the nodes you want and easily insert them into the new ones. Revisit the docs and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I wrote the function find_subs() that resolves your example. You could modify it in a convenient way to resolve a more general problem:

```
import re 

def find_subs(line):
    match = re.findall(">([aA-zZ\s]*)<",line)
    if len(match) != 0:
        new_line = '<ul class="bar">'
        for m in match:
            new_line += "<li>"+m+"</li>"
        new_line += "</ul>"
        return new_line
    else:
        return None

line = "<stats>Some line<br>Other line</stats>"
new = find_subs(line)
print new
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the guidance, I will tweak it as need be :)